# Error installing JDK

Tags: java, windows

I got following error while installing JDK 1.7 on windows 8.

> "Error 1335. The cabinet file 'st170510.cab' required for this
>   installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a
>   network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with
>   this package."

I have downloaded latest version of JDK from oracle foundation. previously JDK 1.6 was installed on my pc. I uninstalled it and tried to install this version and met this error.

For further information, I have already installed JRE 1.7 on my system.

Comment: Have you tried redownloading the JDK install file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error:

```
"Error 1335. The cabinet file 'st170510.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package."
```

is not because of Issue in JDK setup or as such.

Some of the reasons may be:

1. Some research suggests that this problem may arise because of bad RAM.

   Source - https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=65872
2. This is a Windows Installer error that may occur for different cabinet file names located on the installation media (usually on CD).

   Source - [error-1335-the-cabinet-file-filecab-required-for-this-installation-is-corrupt-and-cannot-be-used-this-could-indicate-a-network-error-an-error-reading-from-the-cd-rom-or-a-problem-with-this-package](http://support.f-prot.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/177/16/error-1335-the-cabinet-file-filecab-required-for-this-installation-is-corrupt-and-cannot-be-used-this-could-indicate-a-network-error-an-error-reading-from-the-cd-rom-or-a-problem-with-this-package)
3. Can be caused by User Access Control.

   Source - http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/error-error-1335the-cabinet-file-data1cab-required-installation-corrupt-and-cannot-be-used-co
4. Corrupted installer caused by a firewall or virus software running on your computer.

   Source - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/7992-63-error-1335-help
5. Occur when the installer is unable to access the necessary files from the DVD/CD-ROM drive.

   Source - http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/install-error-1311-1335-or.html

Each link has its own list of steps to resolve the Issue.
Not sure what may be causing Issue in your case.

You can try different solutions and see if any one can help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I think it has something to do with Windows "unblock" feature. (Rich click on file, select "unblock")

We had this issue before when we downloaded a Zip file, extracted an installed, and ran it - it failed - we had to unblock the file first - we also noticed that extracted elements were also "blocked" as well.

Java Install >>- On downloading using windows, file transfer speed was fast until the very end.  then it seemed to stall.
Any attempt to install from these files produced errors and a fail.

Fix >>- I then downloaded it using a MAC and then transferred the files back to the windows box and did the install again.

This time it was perfect - no errors - good install.

Rob

Comment: Yes I had the same error when I had downloaded the executable into my downloads folder. I re-downloaded it to another folder, un-blocked the file in the file properties and it installed just fine (I did all of this in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I was installing Oracle Java 8 JDK (version 111) on a Windows 10 machine. I got the same error as described in the question.

I disabled windows defender (all checkboxes to off), downloaded the file, went to its properties clicked unblock and apply. Then the JDK installed fine.

Comment: unbelievable but that 's true in my case. Windows Defense blocks the installation without any warning, f*** that!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After reading all the answers, I concluded that the downloaded .exe file was getting corrupt each time I download. Initially I used Internet Edge for the download (like 5 times) and I had the problem every time. The problem got solved when I switched to chrome browser, downloaded and installed again.

Comment: Oracle provides SHA256 checksums for their JDK downloads. Using DownThemAll addon for Firefox with the checksum helped me when I got error 1335.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but with 1.8 on windows 7 (tried with jdk8u91 and jdk8u92). None of the other solutions here worked, but unchecking the "source code" and "public jre" options caused the error to not occur. Not a complete solution if you need the source code - the jre is available separately anyway - but it got me through the installer, and the jdk seems functional.

Answer (score 0):

When you meet this problem ,you compare the two files with WinMD5Free after downloading them.
At first I used chrome and IDM to download the JDK files and always met with an error although I changed other versions many times.

Hence I use Firefox download the JDK file and problems are resolved.

^_^

Comment: I installed  jdk8U151  on WIndows 7  Ultimate 64 bits。

Answer (score 0):

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro
**Java**: 10.0.1

When trying to run the JDK installer from the "Downloads" folder I kept running into the same error (only different .cab file). I tried running as admin, different compatibility mode, scanning with the Windows scanner. Nothing helped.

Then I just downloaded to Desktop. I ran it as Administrator and Java installed without any problem.