# Error 1335 While installing a 32 bit JDK on a 64 bit Windows 10 System

Tags: java, windows, java-6, jpcap

I am trying to install the 32 bit JDK version on my 64 bit Windows 10 PC. This is because I am working on a Network capture project using JPCAP and the JPCAP library is only available in the 32 bit version, therefore, I need to compile using the 32 bit JDK.

**Find below the error message I receive when I try to install**
*'Error 1335: the cabinet file st180740.cab required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be use. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the cd-rom, or a problem with this package'*

**Here are the things I have tried so far**
1. I have tried to install both a recent and older JDK version, all still have the same issue.

2. I have tried to download the file to a separate folder on my PC before trying to install, all to no avail
3. I have tried to unlock the exe before runing the installation as an admin, just as suggested in this thread ([Error installing JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476795/error-installing-jdk))
4. Disable my antivirus before starting the installation

All of these did not work.

Does anyone know how else one can work around this problem?

Comment: Installing the 32-bit JDK on a 32-bit system is not usually a problem.  You might try using a silent-mode installation, [as this has been known to work around other bugs in the installer](http://serverfault.com/a/730377/94065).  However, I don't see why you would need to match the *compiler* to the library bitness version?  So long as you use the 32-bit *runtime*, I'd have thought the 64-bit JDK would work perfectly well.

Comment: Its 32bit JDK on a 64 bit windows 10 pc. Also, I have tried out the silent installation as you suggested, but it still didn't work

Comment: Typo.  I meant "installing the 32-bit JDK on a 64-bit system is not usually a problem".

Comment: I still haven't found a fix to it...All d fixes iv seen online didn't work

Comment: Failing all else, there's the old standby: install it on another machine (perhaps a 32-bit one) and copy the files.  The JDK doesn't actually need installation per se.  FWIW, jdk-8u73-windows-i586.exe installs successfully on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine, though that might be because I'm on an insider build (rs1_release 14251).