# How to fix " Error 1335. The cabinet file 'sj180121.cab' " error installing JDK 8

Tags: java, winforms

<= "Error 1335. The cabinet file 'sj180121.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package." =>

There is a big problem occurs when I try to install the JDK 8 on Windows 8.1. Although this is not the first time I installed them. I have tried to find out and fix it on the thread [Error installing JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476795/error-installing-jdk), but there seems no better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of those other solutions too but nothing worked. I can't tell you exactly what fixed the problem but I ran the following programs, rebooted and was able to successfully download and install.

1. Windows "Disk Cleanup"
2. [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)
3. [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)