# Unable To Install Any Version Of Java on Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: java, windows-7, installation, windows-7-x64

**Note**:- Please Read Full.

I am unable to install `java SE 8` which I tried, The installer is unpacked and the installation goes on until it is mid-way, then a message is displayed that the installation files are corrupted. So, I tried to install it with new setup, Which didn't quite work out either. I tried microsoft support on which I found a [troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) which didn't work either.I also tried installing `Java SE 7`, again the same problem was faced by me.

Comment: Download the server jre, it needs no Installation and can be unzipped

Comment: Notes: 1) Don't patronize us with stuff like this: "Note:- Please Read Full".  2) This is not really a programming question at all.  It is a software installation problem.  That makes it *close to* off-topic. 3) There are various causes for this kind of thing; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476795/error-installing-jdk

Comment: Stephen C, this is the best website to solve my problems and this is one of the major problem I am facing. Sorry for an off-topic question. Thank You for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Because you said the files were corrupted and you didn't specify from where you did get them I suggest you to follow this:

First of all: Install Java even if you already have it (it contains the JVM) [download java](https://www.java.com/download/).

Then go here and choose which SE you want to install. I suggest you to install JDK 8.

[download java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like "u" for "you".

Comment: I download from the oracle website, after the first download from oracle i tried a lot of other websites like file-hippo etc. The required installation is only of java se jre. I tried to install both Java SE 7 and Java SE 8 JREs

Comment: i told you te reinstall completely Java , not only Java jre .