# Java SE installation error

Tags: java, failed-installation

I was trying to update my JDK  but have an unusual error. I don't know what it means and how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!
Here is the error.

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered [Error installing JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476795/error-installing-jdk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476795/error-installing-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

Try by downloading the file again and then reinstall it. Because it seems to be the problem of corrupted files.
download link below.
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/10.0.1+10/fb4372174a714e6b8c52526dc134031e/jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe